# Is interleaving local variable declarations with assertions and function calls a bad practice?

Tags: c, assertions, declarations

In my experience, it is customary to place local variable declarations at the beginning of their scope. Several questions in this forum ask whether this needs to be so, and their answers tend to agree on that variables should be declared nearest to their use. This answer suggests a goal of scope minimization, but does not state an opinion on whether declarations should be grouped together or not.

I do think it's cleaner to have declarations (a) grouped together and (b) at the start of their scope. But I also think that interleaving assertions and function calls might help (a) make functions fail faster in an error scenario and (b) add useful restrictions.

### Making functions fail faster

Consider `test_function_1` defined below:

```c
void test_function_1(const int *const param)
{
    assert(NULL != param);

    /* (Function declarations.) */

    /* (Main logic.) */
}
```

Assume that the assertion is reasonable: `test_function_1` needs `param` not to be null. Here, having the assertion precede the declarations helps the function fail faster from an irrecoverable scenario. I have not seen this style before, so I wonder:

**Is there a reason not to do this?**

### Adding useful restrictions

Consider `test_function_2` defined below:

```c
void test_function_2(void)
{
    const int a = get_a(); 

    function_with_side_effects(a);

    const int b = function_affected_by_side_effects();

    /* (Main logic. Assume that 'a' and 'b' are used sufficiently.) */
}
```

Here, having the call to `function_with_side_effects` precede the declaration of `b` allows us to define `b` as a constant. (It is not possible to declare `b` as a constant, then call `function_with_side_effects` and then define `b` with `function_affected_by_side_effects`.) If we do things the traditional way and declare `b` first, not as a constant, then we lose the constraint that is so useful to us.

**Is there a reason not to do this?**

Comment: I don't write C, so I might be missing something that experienced C developers just intrinsically know, but how are the two functions in your question related?

Comment: It's best to validate input parameters as soon as possible. There is no practical reason not to, unless validation is non trivial.

Comment: "it is customary to place local variable declarations at the beginning of their scope." This was forced by a limitation of the language that was fixed over 20 years ago (in C99, IIRC). It's obsolete and bad practice today.

Comment: @Alexander are you saying it's bad practice because it enforces distance between the declaration and the usage of a symbol?

Comment: @GregBurghardt in the context of C, the concept of "side effects" generally implies that an operation affects the state of the program in some way. I have used it in the names of my functions to imply that one of the functions may affect the value returned by the other.

Comment: @SeveroRaz there’s pretty much no upside, besides “it makes the compiler’s stack allocator simpler to implement”. It’s all downsides: 1) needless distance from decl to use, 2) extra lines of code, which isn’t *necessarily* a bad thing, but it definitely is here, since those lines are completely redundant boilerplate, 3) and most importantly, it unnecessarily increases the chance of bugs, caused by scoping variables more widely than necessary. Case in point: as conservative as the Linux code as is, they’re moving C9, *primarily* for tighter scoping of loop variables.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for elaborating. In your last sentence, I presume you're referring to the recent decision to use C11 instead of C89 for the Linux kernel, right?

Comment: @SeveroRaz Ah I meant to type C99, but now I realize they're actually going to C11. Cool

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. You are asking two separate questions about two different styles of writing a function. I thought there was a connection between `test_function_1` and `test_function_2` -- there isn't. Two different examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reason not to do this?

Tradition.

Stupid as it sounds we were forced to do things in certain orders in older languages and we're dragging those old, no longer relevant, habits around. Knowing this you can buck tradition but understand it comes at a cost. Computer don't care but a human will tend to be a stick in the mud. Get your team on board before you try to force change with code.

As for your specific examples:

> **Making functions fail faster**

```
assert(NULL != param);
```

[Assertions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm) are intended for debugging code. They tend to get turned off when code is deployed. If you want this check in operational code consider a [guard clause](https://medium.com/@scadge/if-statements-design-guard-clauses-might-be-all-you-need-67219a1a981a). Which is a fancy way to say just write an if. One that will send us elsewhere if things aren't right. Now this is *c*. No exceptions to throw. So all you can do is write to stderr and abort the program if you don't have an error handling block to go to. The nice thing about having them first is nothing got allocated yet so nothing needs de-allocation. There is a long tradition of putting guard clauses first.

> **Adding useful restrictions**

Remember that a style guide is only a guide. What really counts is how your team feels. Personally I do not feel compelled to move every declaration to the top of a function. But when this comes up I start to suspect that a functions body is too long and needs decomposing.

Rather that fly directly at this problem you can choose to side step it. I know this is an example so my side step wont work for all the cases where you find this problem, but at least in this case there is nice way to avoid this issue:

```
int a_to_b(const int *const a)
{
    function_with_side_effects(a);
    return function_affected_by_side_effects();
}
```

With that this becomes a non-issue:

```
void test_function_2(void)
{
    const int a = get_a(); 
    const int b = a_to_b(a);

    /* (Main logic. Assume that 'a' and 'b' are used sufficiently.) */
}
```

Done this way the [temporal coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) is explicit (you can't call `a_to_b()` without an `a`) and related code is still grouped together.

But yes, you can't always do that. I do not mind things getting declared near where they're used. I also do not mind short functions. So long as they have good names.